# Classify data using mahout

Tags: apache, hadoop, machine-learning, mahout

I'm new to Apache Mahout and working on a classsification problem.

The Problem states:
 There exists a set of data in a text file and I need to fetch some or all of the data from the file depending upon the given span of time.

Span of time : Each record would have a Date of transaction.
 So, time span would be calculated using the logic (Sys_Date - Transaction_Date).

Thus, output would vary depending upon whether data is required for last month / week / specific number of days.
 How can this filtering be achieved using Apache Mahout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been working properly with hadoop yet. But it seems to me that this video should help:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwW7bQRykHI&feature=player_embedded

After the filtering, you can use result in mahout (for solving the classification problem)

Comment: Agreed, this is more of a pre-processing / data wrangling stuff. But, this certainly helps. Thanks @xhudik

Answer (score 1):

This by itself does not sound like a machine learning problem at all. You want to put your data in a database of some kind and query for records in a date range. Then, you want to do something with that data. This is not something ML tools do.

Comment: I think, it is relevant question. hadoop, mahout are considered as ML tools. Yes, you are right it has nothing to do with some ML algorithm, but it is about data pre-processing which is often the most time-consuming task in ML